# whats the maximum poly count for character models in video games?

Tags: polycount

So I have a 3d human model that I made in blender and it has almost 14,000 vertices, almost 14,000 faces, and tris are at almost 28 thousand. Will it be okay for me to use this model with out the need of retopology and baking normals and ambient occlusion. Even though you cant see the model I've made, all I can say is that it looks somewhat high poly-ish(with-out subsurface modifier). I modeled the mesh from my own character reference and pretty much feel great about the outcome. Though, certain parts of the mesh I had to sculpt, but with out the "Dynamic Topology" tool option in the Blender sculpting section.

I've heard poly count depends on your project's gameplay style. But The gameplay mechanic i'm going for will be no more than 3 characters in the gameplay.

Let me know what you think, thanks.

Comment: Imho in the end it depends also on the expected processing power of your game's target devices. And you could also privide different level details as an option...

Comment: Keep it low as possible and maintain the silhouette of the character. The stressing should be on texturing and normal mapping. Depends upon your target devices, even process heavy games are mostly heavy because of the texture sizes and shadow quality.